Who sent the threatening text messages?
In the 2024 Thriller series A Good Girl's Guide to Murder, the protagonist Pip investigates a 5 years old murder of Andie Bell, which her boyfriend Sal had already been convicted for. Pip believes Sal was innocent, and the actual killer is still roaming free. When she starts investigating, she gets threatening text messages from an unknown number, asking her to stop. Also, she gets a threatening note saying "Stop digging".
When Pip keeps going despite the threats, the one who sent the texts

 kidnaps and kills Pip's dog, Barney.

At the season finale, it was revealed that

 Elliot was the one who made Sal send a false confession and killed him, and then made his death look like a suicide. He was also the one who sent the threatening note. But, he swears he did not kill Andie. And it becomes evident he did not send those texts or kill the dog. At the end it's revealed, it was Becca (Andie's sister) who accidentally killed Andie and hid her body in a cave, so both murders are solved.

But, the killer never mentions anything about the texts or

 killing Pip's dog

when they reveal the truth to Pip.
So, that leaves us with, who sent those texts and did that other heinous crime?
